# Upgrading a rails 6 app to 7 with ransack: "LoadError: cannot load such file -- ransack/nodes"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ransack

I'm upgrading an existing rails app (fat_free_crm) to rails7. I've upgrade a number of gems and rails itself, however when I run a rake task, I am seeing error:

```
rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- ransack/nodes
/pwd/fat_free_crm/config/application.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

I don't see any mention of the `nodes` in any ransack docs, the ransack_ui gem, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`ransack_ui` looks unmaintained. You have to drop it or downgrade ransack to `v3` which still has [*ransack/nodes.rb*](https://github.com/activerecord-hackery/ransack/blob/v3.2.1/lib/ransack/nodes.rb) file. Or even `v2` because latest ransack_ui version added a version constraint on it:

```rb
gem.add_dependency 'ransack', '~> 2.0'
```

it also depends on `ransack_chronic` which has all but 3 commits and is 11 years old:

*https://github.com/ndbroadbent/ransack_chronic/blob/master/lib/ransack_overrides/nodes/value.rb#L1*

```rb
require 'ransack/nodes' # <= ransack v4 doesn't have that file

# Add Chronic parsing to date and time casting
module Ransack
  module Nodes
...
```

or just fork it and fix it, because it doesn't look like these two gems will get any significant updates.

Comment: getting a different error now :) thanks for this. I didn't think of going that far back in the version history of ransack.